# ERROR 1064 (42000):You have an error in your SQL syntax; near '' at line 15

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I just want to create simple function in mysql 5.7 but getting below error ....

tried all possible ways ....but no luck....Please find the mistake.

Table :
select * from emp_tab;
+-------+---------+------+--------+
| empno | ename   | sal  | deptno |

+-------+---------+------+--------+
|  7101 | Martin  | 4000 |     10 |

function syntax:

mysql> create function employeebonus(eno int(10))

```
-> returns double deterministic
-> begin
-> declare temp double;
-> declare bonus double;
-> select sal into temp from emp_tab where empno=eno;
-> if temp<=10000 then
-> set bonus=temp*0.10;
-> else if temp<=20000 then
-> set bonus=temp*0.20;
-> else
-> set bonus=temp*0.30;
-> end if;
-> return bonus;
-> end$$
```

at 15 th line , tried with another syntax
->end;
->$$
and
->end
->$$

but nothing got worked

ERROR 1064 (42000):You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error in this line ...

else if temp<=20000 then

This line should be corrected as

elseif temp<=20000 then

no space between "else  if" ...its "elseif"